# How to attach functions to structs

Tags: go, struct

I have 2 functions: `GetRequest` that has 3 arguments and returns `*http.Request` and `RunRequest` that has `*http.Request` as an argument and resp, content, err as results and I'm trying to connect them together like:
`resp, content, err := myStruct.RunRequest(args for GetRequest)`

```
type myStruct struct {}
func GetRequest(method string, path string, token string, body interface{}) (req *http.Request, err error) {...}
func RunRequest(req *http.Request) (resp *http.Response, content []byte, err error) {...}
resp, content, err := myStruct.RunRequest("GET", "/users", "", nil)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Go this is called "defining a method on a type". It works like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

type Vertex struct {
    X, Y float64
}

func (v Vertex) Abs() float64 {
    return math.Sqrt(v.X*v.X + v.Y*v.Y)
}

func main() {
    v := Vertex{3, 4}
    fmt.Println(v.Abs())
}
```

This example is taken straight from the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/methods/1) which I highly recommend any newcomer should take.

Comment: Thanks. I read this before, but when you said what is it called, I found [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/defining-methods-in-go) and I think its a better article.